# How to make an HTML form print two files

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, perl

I use the following chunk of HTML to represent a (hidden) form containing data of interest that I want to process and print to a file, when activated:

```
<form id="output_form" action="exportData.pl" method="POST" target="_blank" style="display:none;">
  <input type="text" id="output_form_data" name="output_data" style="">
  <input type="text" id="output_form_filename" name="output_filename" style="">
</form>
```

When I submit this form, data are sent to `exportData.pl`, which in turn prints the `output_data` data to the specified filename in the variable `output_filename`.

Very roughly:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;

my $val = param('output_data');
my $fn = param('output_filename');

print "Content-Type: text/plain\n";
print "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fn\n";
print "Content-Description: File to download\n\n";

print "$val\r\n";
```

What I would like to do is export two files on submitting this form, not just one. The second file will be processed with a different script so that the output is changed.

What I have tried so far:

I set up two hidden forms:

```
<form id="output_form_1" action="exportData_1.pl" method="POST" target="_blank" style="display:none;">
  <input type="text" id="output_form_data_1" name="output_data" style="">
  <input type="text" id="output_form_filename_1" name="output_filename" style="">
</form>
<form id="output_form_2" action="exportData_2.pl" method="POST" target="_blank" style="display:none;">
  <input type="text" id="output_form_data_2" name="output_data" style="">
  <input type="text" id="output_form_filename_2" name="output_filename" style="">
</form>
```

When I click on a button, I use jQuery to fire a JavaScript function `ExportData()` that runs `submit()` on both forms:

```
function ExportData()
{
    var rawTxt = document.getElementById("results_map").innerHTML;

    var fn_1 = exportFilename(".1.tsv");
    $('#output_form_data_1').val(rawTxt);
    $('#output_form_filename_1').val(fn_1);
    $('#output_form_1').submit();

    var fn_2 = exportFilename(".2.tsv");
    $('#output_form_data_2').val(rawTxt);
    $('#output_form_filename_2').val(fn_2);
    $('#output_form_2').submit();
};
```

However, `submit()` is only called on the form `output_form_1`. Nothing happens with the second form `output_form_2`.

How can I submit two hidden forms to print two different files out? Failing that, how would I do this by other means? (Note that, if I use client-side tricks, I cannot use Flash or Java, and I would need to be able to support IE users.)

Comment: Have the form return a page containing two hidden iframes. Each of these iframes points to a script that downloads one of the files.

Answer (score 0):

Submit your forms with AJAX. What happens in your case is when the first form is about to be submitted POST request to `exportData_1.pl` starts and code execution on the current page stops.

By using AJAX technique 2 separate POST requests will be made without navigating away from your page.

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725810/php-form-submit-converting-to-jquery-ajax) explains how it can be achieved.

**UPD**: Sorry, kind of just focused on the problem and ignored the fact that you want to download files on each form submit. It's not possible with javascript (not in all browsers).

The alternative that works in old IE browsers as well would be to use 2 iframes each containing one of your forms:

```
<iframe src="firstFormPage.html"></iframe>
<iframe src="secondFormPage.html"></iframe>
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3S9XL/)

That approach would allow you to make form submits inside iframes without causing your main page to reload.

**UPD2**: To modify form fields inside iframes:

```
<iframe id="form1" src="form1.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<iframe id="form2" src="form2.html" frameborder="0"></iframe><br/>
<input id="editForms" type="button" value="Edit Forms"/>

<script>
    $('#editForms').click(function(){
        $('#form1').contents().find('#input').val("Modifed in frame 1");
        $('#form2').contents().find('#input').val("Modifed in frame 2");
    });
</script>
```

[demo](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11211060/test/main.html)

Comment: This does not work — while the request is successful, instead of the response (`output_form_data`) being printed to a file, the response ends up trapped in the AJAX `success` callback function. Do you have a code example that explicitly demonstrates how to get the Perl script to print data to a file, instead of sending the data to the AJAX response handler?

Comment: Thanks for following up. My project needs to support all modern web browsers.

Comment: The updated solution should work in most browsers. What I meant is that serving files with javascript might not be supported by older browsers, iframes are still fine.